# jQuery Loading images synchronously with .load

Tags: jquery, image, load, asynchronous

```
function loadImage(url) {

    var retval=0;

    var img = new Image();

    $(img).attr('src', url)
          .appendTo("#test")
          .load( function() {
                $(this).hide().fadeIn();
                retval=true;
          })
          .error( function() {
              $(this).remove();
              retval=false;
          });

    return retval;

}
```

This function always returns 0 :(

I guess that I can't overwrite the global variable (retval) because of the asynchronously behavoir of the .load function. Any ideas for a workaround? I namely would like that the function also indicates if the given remote image exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function loadImage(url) {

var retval=0;

var img = new Image();

$(img).load( function() {
            $(this).hide().fadeIn();
            retval=true;
      })
      .error( function() {
          $(this).remove();
          retval=false;
      })
      .attr('src', url)
      .appendTo("#test")
      ;

return retval;

}
```

You're binding event handlers (load and error) after you've done the loading and appending itself.

EDIT: removed suggestion to return the value from the events (won't work ofcourse)

Comment: Same result as with my snipped. And if I let return true/false from within the event handlers, the loadImage function logically doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ah, the code you return is returned before the image is loaded(asynchronous), hence the value is still 0. Try to set retval as -1 and set a timeout that calls itself each 500ms and only returns the retval when it's different then -1.

Comment: @lorus Did it work? Please reply or mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: function checkChange() {
  if (retval == -1)  {
   setTimeout(checkChange(),500);
  }
 }
 
 checkChange();

Comment: did you mean something like this? I run in an "too much recursion"-error :-/

Comment: Is there maybe any way to use the load-function synchronously like with ajax() and $.ajaxSetup({ async:false }) ?

Comment: add a function around the checkChange in your SetTimeout. Otherwise it is called instantly, and a recursion error occurs:

function checkChange() { if (retval == -1) { setTimeout(function() {checkChange()},500); } } checkChange();